# Are semi-continuous variables unique to lp_solve or do other MILP optimizers have them?

Tags: r, linear-programming

I used LP_solve under R using `lpSolveAPI` and used its semi-continuous variable type which is one in which it has a bound (ie. 100 to 300) but can also take a value of 0.

I'm looking at the `ROI` package, in particular the `symphony` plugin.  Under `ROI` I don't see anything about semi-continuous variables nor do I see anything under the symphony plugin docs.  I perused the actual Symphony documentation but I didn't see anything there suggesting it also had this feature.

I'm thinking the best work around would be to make a binary variable which is

`binary * max - variable * 1 >=0`

and then

`binary * min - variable *1 >=0`

Is this the best approach or are there better ones?

Comment: Most commercial solvers have them (Cplex, Gurobi, Xpress do). COIN CBC also has them. Using a single binary variable b: `b*LO  <= x <= b*UP`  is a good alternative approach.